# Randomly spawn power ups using a timer xna c#

Tags: c#, list, random, timer, xna

I am creating a 2D game and I've hit a serious road block when trying to 'randomly' spawn power ups. Basically what I am attempting to do is spawn the power ups off screen and then they move onto the screen (at the same speed as my scrolling background) Once one of the three power ups has been spawned another one won't spawn until 10 to 30 seconds has passed. I also understand that the shield power Up is the only one that I am trying to get spawning randomly at the moment. I have been researching for hours and writing code that I will post below. I have tried to do this all by myself so I apologize for the quality of the code, I am still a novice and learning. Any help or links to websites would be greatly appreciated as I have no idea where to proceed from here. 
    Thanks in advance.

**game1.cs**

```
public List<PowerUps> powerUpList = new List<PowerUps>();
public double counterPower = 0;
public bool powerUpCollision = false;
public bool invincibility = false;
Sprite shieldPower;
Sprite infiniteAmmoPower;
Sprite livesPower;
bool isVisible = true;
public bool infiniteAmmoBool = false;
public bool infiniteAmmoCol = false;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    shieldPower = new Sprite();
    infiniteAmmoPower = new Sprite();
    livesPower = new Sprite();
}
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    shieldPower.LoadContent(this.Content, "powerUpShield");
    infiniteAmmoPower.LoadContent(this.Content, "infinitePowerUp");
    livesPower.LoadContent(this.Content, "livePowerUp");
}

protected override void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
{

}
public void powerUps(GameTime theGameTime)
{
    //if (mPlayer.boundingBox.Intersects(shieldPower.boundingBoxShieldPower))

    {
        Console.WriteLine(shieldPower.Position.X);
        if (shieldPower.isVisible == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("collision working");
            powerUpCollision = true;
            invincibility = true;
            shieldPower.isVisible = false;
            if (powerUpCollision == true && invincibility == true)
            {
                lives = lives - 0;
            }
            counterPower = 0;
        }
    }
    counterPower += theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    {
        //  Console.WriteLine(counterPower);
        if (counterPower > 7)
        {
            powerUpCollision = false;
            invincibility = false;

        }
    }



    if (mPlayer.boundingBox.Intersects(livesPower.boundingBoxLives))
    {
        if (livesPower.isVisible == true)
        {
            lives = lives + 1;
            livesPower.isVisible = false;
        }
    }
}


public void loadPowerUps()
{
    int randPowerX = random.Next(850, 1400); // spawns randomly between these coordinates
    int randPowerY = random.Next(-300, 300);
    Console.WriteLine(shieldPower.Position.X);
    if (powerUpList.Count < 1) // limits the powerUp count to 1 at a time
    {
        powerUpList.Add(new PowerUps(Content.Load<Texture2D>("powerUpShield"), new Vector2(randPowerX, randPowerY)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < powerUpList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (powerUpList[i].isVisible == false)
        {
            powerUpList.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime theGameTime)
{
    foreach (PowerUps powerup in powerUpList)
    {
        powerup.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    mPlayer.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    enemyShip.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    if (shieldPower.isVisible == true)
    {
        shieldPower.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    }
    if (livesPower.isVisible == true)
    {
        livesPower.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    }
    if (infiniteAmmoPower.isVisible == true)
    {
        infiniteAmmoPower.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

**PowerUps.cs**

```
public class PowerUps : Game1
{

    Random randomPower = new Random();
    int minPowerSpawnTimer = 10000; // 10 seconds 
    int maxPowerSpawnTimer = 30000; // 30 seconds
    double nextSpawnTime;
    float powerUpSpeed = -0.5f;
    Vector2 position;
    Texture2D texture;



    public PowerUps(Texture2D newText, Vector2 newPos)
    {
        position = newPos;
        texture = newText;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {

        position.X += powerUpSpeed;
        nextSpawnTime -= theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (nextSpawnTime < 0)
        {
            loadPowerUps();
            resetSpawnTime();
        }

    }

    public void resetSpawnTime()
    {
        nextSpawnTime = randomPower.Next(minPowerSpawnTimer, maxPowerSpawnTimer);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: The value theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds, is positive, and you are adding that value to nextSpawnTime. Therefore, nextSpawnTime will never be < 0.
It's very helpful to specify exactly what isn't working (nothing is spawning, nothing is drawing), and even better to indicate what you've tried to diagnose or fix the problem.

Comment: I never noticed that. It has been changed but still the issue itself still remains. I suppose I am one step closer though. Thank you for your comment, Griffin.

Comment: The shield Sprite itself isn't drawing. I have traced the X position of the sprite and it is returning 0. the other two sprites are drawing but they are static and I have defined their position already. The shield Sprite (the one I'm trying spawn randomly for now) isn't. Sorry for not clarifying that at the start.

Comment: in terms of things I have done to try and fix the problem, I've pretty much just research into lists and timers, however both of these have proved little help. I am struggling to come up with a solution for this persistent problem so I turned to Stackoverflow to see if anyone could shed any light on my problem, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the class structure you've created. Your should not be inheriting `Game1` in your `PowerUps` class. It is creating multiple instances of `Game1` objects each of which has its own list of PowerUps.

It doesn't appear to me that any of the `Update()` methods in the `PowerUps` instances will ever be called.

I think you may be wanting to access functionallity of your `Game1` class from your `PowerUps` class. Inheriting (`PowerUps : Game1`) is not the way to do it here.

Instead, make a PowerUps class that does not inherit anything. Then from your Game1 Update method, call your PowerUps instances' Update method and pass what variables it needs. Same with the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your `Update` method to be called, your `PowerUps` class must inherit from `GameComponent`, not `Game1`.

Since you also have a `Draw` method, to have your `Draw` method also called automatically your must inherit from `DrawableGameComponent` instead.

Those base classes take your `Game1` as a parameter, so you will have to modify your constructor:

```
public class PowerUps : DrawableGameComponent
{
    //Variables
    public PowerUps(Texture2D newText, Vector2 newPos, Game1 game) : base(game)
    {
        position = newPos;
        texture = newText;
    }
```

Now that you have a `GameComponent`, you must register it in your `Game1` class upon creation. So, when creating your power ups in your `powerUpList`, change your code from

```
powerUpList.Add(new PowerUps(Content.Load<Texture2D>("powerUpShield"), new Vector2(randPowerX, randPowerY)));
```

to:

```
PowerUps powerUp = new PowerUps(Content.Load<Texture2D>("powerUpShield"), new Vector2(randPowerX, randPowerY))
powerUpList.Add(powerUp);
Components.Add(powerUp);
```

When your component is registered within the `Components` list, the Game can start calling the `Draw` and `Update` methods of your component. Once you're finish with it, remove it from the list.